# Objective c : How to fetch data from sqlite table as per primary key?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

Say I am having 1 table called ABC with fields ABCid,ABCname,ABCImagePath,ABCSequence. Now this table contains more than 40 rows inside the same.

Now I have an array of numbers say 1,4,5,7,8 and I want to compare these numbers with ABCid and fetch all the data from table ABC as per these IDs.

```
        + (void) getSelectedData : (int)ABCId
        {   
        NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];    
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];     

                if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSString *query =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from [ABC] where ABCId=%d",ABCId];
                    const char *sql = [query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                            sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;       

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        [self getInitialDataToDisplay:dbPath]; 
                        ABC *DataObj = [[ABC alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:ABCId];


                        DataObj.ABCName =    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                        ABCImagePath =   [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
                        DataObj.ABCSequence = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt,8);
                        [appDelegate.arrGetData addObject:DataObj];         }
                    else
                    {
                        NSAssert1(0,@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                    }
                    NSLog(@"%d",[appDelegate.DataArrayTrans count]);
                        }
                else
                    sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory. 
}
```

But app gets crashed in the if condition. Also note that I use below lines from the pageController to call the above function from ABC Object file.

```
for(int i=0;i<[arrRId count];i++)
{
    [ABC getSelectedData:[[arrRId objectAtIndex:i]integerValue]];
    [arr576576 addObject:[appDelegate.arrGetData valueForKey:@"ABCId"]];
}
```

Please guide me where I am making mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you use Core Data ?

Answer (score 0):

your query should be like this **select * from ABC where ABCId IN (1,4,5,7,8)**
that's it.